How to get post-id for Facebook Graph API to get post comments
According to Facebook Graph API, I need the postId or the objectId to fetch the comments on the specific post, but upon visiting the post, the url gives a hashed parameters so I am unable to get the postId.
BUT if the post contains a photo, I can click on that photo and get its Id, then I can get the comment but for that photo only not on the post itself.
So how can I get the postId when Facebook only gives a hashed value when vieweing the post?

I got it.
I can get the postId if I am an Administrator of the page through Meta Business Suite accessible via:

Go to Page Profile
Click Professional Dashboard
Scroll down and click Meta Business Suite
Click Content
Click the post and it will show you the PostId

To use the it to get the comments, you will need the graph url:
https://graph.facebook.com/pageId_postId/comments
So you will still be needing the pageId which you can find via:

Go to Page Profile
Click About
Click Page Transparency

